# DateTime accumalator LINQ function

Tags: c#, linq

For the life of me, I can't think of how to do this with LINQ:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= message.RoomBookingDto.Length; i++)
{
    timesToCheck.Add(
        i == 0 
            ? message.RoomBookingDto.BookedOn.AddHours(1) 
            : timesToCheck[i - 1].AddHours(1));
}
```

So `Length` is the number of hours a `Room` has been booked out for. `BookedOn` is the date and time of the booking.

So basically what I want is that if the length is 3 (hours) and they booked on `06-08-2015 18:00`, I want to have a list generated:

```
List<DateTime> 
   {
      "06-08-2015 19:00",
      "06-08-2015 20:00",
      "06-08-2015 21:00"
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx) to build a sequence and then process that sequence using `Select`:

```
var timesToCheck = Enumerable.Range(1, message.RoomBookingDto.Length)
    .Select(i => message.RoomBookingDto.BookedOn.AddHours(i))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: That is a neat thing to do, I like that. Cheers

Comment: This code also needs `i + 1` to be correct according to the original example.

Comment: @driis.  The range is starting at one, so it does not need to be `i+1`

Answer (score 2):

Unless i missed something subtle, you can use the Select overload that also supllies an index parameter to the selector:

```
timesToCheck = message.RoomBookingDto.Select((x,i) => 
    message.RoomBookingDto.BookedOn.AddHours(i+1)).ToList();
```

Comment: That's what I wanted, didn't know you could pull the index in!

Comment: so the subtle thing you may have missed was that room booking dto has `BookedOn` and `Length` property it isn't an `IEnumerable`

Comment: Right, in that case you need to generate something enumerable to iterate over. I'd recommend @shf301's answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if LINQ is the answer here. There is a better simplification. I believe this code does the same thing.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= message.RoomBookingDto.Length; i++)
{
    timesToCheck.Add(message.RoomBookingDto.BookedOn.AddHours(i));
}
```

Basically using AddHours(i) to simplify things.
Maybe you would also want to store message.RoomBookingDto.BookedOn in a tmp variable to save on that lookup each time through the loop.

Comment: The first iteration adds one hour, so you actually need `AddHours(i+1)`.